# Drupal 8 jQuery is undefined in module twig view

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am trying to develop my first Drupal 8 module and I cannot understand why jQuery is undefined in my twig template.

In my block I call controller function:

```
public function build() {
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
    $slider = new OsTouchController;

    return $slider->displaySlider($config['id']);    
}
```

Then in controller:

```
public function displaySlider($slider_id) {
    $oss_params = $this->getSliderParams($slider_id);
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'slider_default',
      '#oss_params' => $oss_params,
      '#attached' => array(
            'library' =>  array(
                'ostouch_slider/ostouch.slider' 
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

and finally in twig I have such script code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var mySliderSetings = new osSliderSettings("#dragable-settings-block",{
        crop :                        {{ oss_params.crop_image }},
        parallax :                    {{ oss_params.parallax }},
        imageWidth:                   {{ oss_params.image_width }},
        imageHeight:                  {{ oss_params.image_height }},
        site_path :                   '{{ "http://" }}',
        moduleId :                    {{ oss_params.modId }},
        lazyLoading :                 {{ oss_params.lazyLoading }},
        lazyLoadingInPrevNext :       {{ oss_params.lazyLoadingInPrevNext }},
        lazyLoadingInPrevNextAmount : {{ oss_params.lazyLoadingInPrevNextAmount }},
        textOrdering:                 {{ oss_params.textOrdering }},
        screenW :                     screenW,
        screenH :                     screenH,
        setupAnimation :              setupAnimation,
        swiperSlider :                mySwiper
      });
    });
```

Of course I get an error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

because all scripts includes are in the bottom of the page.

I can't find function for script which can help me to display my script code in the bottom of the page.
I can't write this code in js file because params in script can changes.
I can read params from hidden input but I think in Drupal exist another way...

Who can help me? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use Drupal.behaviors instead of document.ready. Read about it [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/node/2269515).

eg.

```
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
      var mySliderSetings = new osSliderSettings("#dragable-settings-block",{
        crop :                        {{ oss_params.crop_image }},
        parallax :                    {{ oss_params.parallax }},
        imageWidth:                   {{ oss_params.image_width }},
        imageHeight:                  {{ oss_params.image_height }},
        site_path :                   '{{ "http://" }}',
        moduleId :                    {{ oss_params.modId }},
        lazyLoading :                 {{ oss_params.lazyLoading }},
        lazyLoadingInPrevNext :       {{ oss_params.lazyLoadingInPrevNext }},
        lazyLoadingInPrevNextAmount : {{ oss_params.lazyLoadingInPrevNextAmount }},
        textOrdering:                 {{ oss_params.textOrdering }},
        screenW :                     screenW,
        screenH :                     screenH,
        setupAnimation :              setupAnimation,
        swiperSlider :                mySwiper
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: I am trying use behavior, but i get the same error (jQuery or Drupal is not defined).When i use my script in some custom.js file it works fine but not in twig.
Can i use script in twig template?
Maybe i have mistake when i call template in my controller?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being loaded on the page?

Comment: Yes. After load page i call jQuery function in console and it is working. jQuery included in the bottom of the page.

Comment: Besides i inspect core modules and find Drupal.behaviors only in .js file not in twig.I think that the main problem is that twig view renders before script includes. 
Can i pass some variables from controller in .js file through drupal function?